# Setting a default value of combo which uses store

Tags: extjs

New to Extjs. I m trying to change the default value of Combo box by using afterrender. Here is what I have been trying:

```
xtype: 'combo',
fieldLabel: 'Post Method',
name: 'postMethod',
store: Chem.getPostMethod(),
valueField: 'id',
value: 0,
displayField: 'method',
triggerAction: 'all',
mode: 'local',
optional: 0,
hidden: true,
allowBlank: false,
listeners: {
     afterrender: function (combo) {
        var store = combo.getStore();
        if (combo.getValue() === 0) {
           combo.setValue(store.getAt(1).get(combo.valueField));
        }
}
}
```

And my ArrayStore is as follows:

```
Chem.getPostMethod = function () {
    return new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        id: 0,
        fields: ['id', 'method'],
        data: [
            [1, 'Post Url'],
            [2, 'Json']
        ],
    })
};
```

Am I doing something wrong? It can't change the value. I have put a debugger and tried changing the value manually by using

```
combo.setValue('2')
```

which gives an undefined result. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is you are trying to set a value **0** to combo, which is not available in store. As a result the value is not set to 0 and getValue() is returning null instead of 0, so the solution would be to check for existence of value instead of comparing it to 0.

```
afterrender: function (combo) {
    var store = combo.getStore();
    if (!combo.getValue()) {
        combo.setValue(store.getAt(1).get(combo.valueField));
    }
}
```

For setValue call you are passing the wrong datatype, so the value is not getting selected. It should be combo.setValue(2) instead of combo.setValue('2')

Comment: Nothing worked. I don't know whats causing this not to work.

Comment: BTW, which version of ExtJS are you using ?

Comment: I m using Sencha 3.4.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess there might be some problem in the code, some code must be overriding it somewhere. Although it did't solve my problem, but I appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Afterrender may be too early, if you are using ExtJS 6. In ExtJS 6, the corresponding event is `boxready`.

Furthermore I would recommend to use `combobox.select()`.

```
boxready:function() {
   if(store.isLoaded()) {
        combo.select(store.getAt(1));
    } else {
        store.on({
            load:function() {
                combo.select(store.getAt(1))
            },
            single:true
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same pattern in an app:

```
afterrender: function(combo) {   
  if(combo!== undefined) {
     var recordSelected = combo.getStore().getAt(0);                     
     if(recordSelected!== undefined) {
         combo.setValue(recordSelected.get('AN'));
     }
  }
}
```

The difference I can see it's maybe your store is not loaded before the afterRender. If it's not, maybe you will have to use the listeners `load` on your arrayStore to perform the setValue instead of afterrender.